# Docker pull failed with request canceled while waiting for connection

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am trying to pull images to default docker machine. But I always get

```
docker@default:/etc$ docker run hellow-world
Unable to find image 'hellow-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
docker@default:/etc$
```

Even if i give --dns option same error

```
docker@default:/etc$ docker run hellow-world --dns=8.8.8.8
Unable to find image 'hellow-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
docker@default:/etc$
```

Tried adding DNS to config.json of the default machine

```
"EngineOptions": {
    "Dns": [
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4"
    ]
}
```

resolv.conf has following entry in default machine

```
docker@default:/etc$
docker@default:/etc$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search <company name>
nameserver 10.0.2.3
docker@default:/etc$
```

This machine sits behind the proxy and I am using kitematic for creating default machine

Kitematic is started by a custom script which will set proxies and start kitematic

Recommended and All images are displayed at the start of kitematic. But can not pull any images

Creating new machine also gives warning

```
PS C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\kitematic> docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 test
Running pre-create checks...
(test) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:  Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
Creating machine...
(test) Unable to get the latest Boot2Docker ISO release version:  Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/latest: dial tcp 192.30.253.116:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Machine created with `--dns` option also has `/etc/resolv.conf` not as `8.8.8.8`

```
docker@test:~$
docker@test:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search <company name>
nameserver 10.0.2.3
docker@test:~$
```

PS:Issue solved after adding HTTP_PROXY to /var/lib/boot2docker/profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution

Either 
add `HTTP_PROXY` to `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`
or

create docker machine with  `--engine-env HTTP_PROXY=IP:PORT`

Answer (score 0):

When pulling an image from an **internal** harbor (defined as SOLELY registry-mirror in /etc/docker/daemon.json because external traffic is **not allowed**) I got that error "Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)." after some layers where downloaded and extracted **successfully**.

**Reason**: disk was out of space
**Solution**: increase diskspace (after that the timeout to registry-1.docker.io was gone)

Why docker tried to pull from a registry that was not defined in the docker configuration I don't know.
In `journalctl -u dockerd` it showed something like "level=info ... Attempting next endpoint for pull after error.... no space left on device"
Why is was not shown as error Is unclear to me. Maybe there is an internal mechanism, that after fetching a layer from a registry fails for whatever reason it tries to fallback to registry-1.docker.io